# blackberry recording audio for VOIP application

Tags: blackberry, voip

in blacberry is there any way to record audio for VOIP application , i am able to do a simple recording application and save it to a file in phone( or how can i modify this so that i can stream), is it possible to capture sound and at the same time delivering it to a server rather than recording , is there any opensource projects on this topic?

recording part is here

```
    recorder.setRecordStream(dataOut);   //recorder is RecordControl
                                         //dataOut is ByteArrayOutputStream
    recorder.startRecord();
```

currently i am saving the recorded details to a ByteArrayOutputStream  and at the end of recording saving it to a file like this

```
`writeToFile(dataOut.toByteArray(), location + "/audio.amr");`

***How Can i modify this so that i can stream recorded data as soon as i get?***
```

Answer (score 0):

Well I am not sure if I understand your question.
If you want to send the audio stream directly to the server while recording  I guess you could access your ByteArrayOutputStream (dataOut) in a separate thread, get the bytes from the stream, wrap them in RTP packages and send them to the streaming server. This separate thread would be running together with the recording process. In this way you don't need to save the audio stream in any file.
Have you tried this approach? Which streaming server are you using?